# How can I backup all of my Facebook?

Tags: facebook, backup

If I want to have a backup of my Facebook what do I have to do? Please show me a way to get a backup of my Facebook data.

Comment: I do not get your question. What is the utility of backing up all your facebook? It is all there, stored in your profile, pictures, messages and apps. It's not going anywhere with your timeline.

Comment: Have you looked at this Facebook help topic? [Downloading Your Info](http://www.facebook.com/help/131112897028467/)

Answer (score 5):

You can download all your Facebook account following this guide : https://www.facebook.com/help/131112897028467/

1. Click the account menu  at the top right of any Facebook page
2. Choose Account Settings
3. Click on "Download a copy of your Facebook data"
4. Click Start My Archive

It will download all your Facebook data :

- Your timeline information (ex: your contact information, interests, groups)
- Content that you and your friends have posted to your timeline
- Photos and videos that you have uploaded to your account
- Your friend list
- Notes you have created
- Events to which you have RSVP’d
- Your sent and received messages
- Any comments that you and your friends have made on your timeline posts, photos, and other timeline content